# Setting default property value when using groovy @Builder

Tags: groovy

It seems that setting a default value for a class property,  is not honored by @Builder.

```
@Test
void test() {
    assert Foo.builder().build().getProp() != null // fail
}

@Builder
class Foo {
    Map prop = [:]
}
```

I'll probably fix this by overriding the build method but how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Values in groovy @Builder AST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066664/default-values-in-groovy-builder-ast)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about the implementation of `builder()` method of `@Builder`.

I believe you need to initialize the properties / members of the class, then do `.build()` to create the instance of the class.

Here is the example:

```
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder

@Builder
class Foo {
    Map prop
}

def map = [a:1, b:2]
def f = Foo.builder().prop(map).build()
assert map == f.prop // or you can use f.getProp()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/QyypPk)</kbd>
If you notice, the demo example shows *how you can initialize multiple properties* while building the object.